# how to speed up gensim word2vec initialization with pre proccessed corpus?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

i am training multiple word2vec models on the same corpus. (i am doing this to study the variation in learned word vectors)

i am using this tutorial as reference: https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/

it is suggested that by default gensim.models.word2vec will iterate over the corpus at least twice. once for initialization and then again for training (iterating the number of epochs specified)

since i am always using the same corpus, i want to save time by initializing only once, and providing the same initialization as input to all successive models.

how can this be done?

this is my current setting:

```py
subdirectory = 'corpus_directory'
for i in range(10):
    sentences = MySentences(subdirectory) # a memory-friendly iterator
    model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=20, size=100, workers=4)
    model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=1)
    word_vectors = model.wv
    fname = 'WV{}.kv'
    word_vectors.save(fname.format(i))
```

where MySentences is defined similarly to the tutorial:
(i made a slight change, so the order of corpus sentences would be shuffled with each initialization)

```py
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname
        self.file_list = [fname for fname in os.listdir(dirname) if fname.endswith('.txt')]
        random.shuffle(self.file_list)

    def __iter__(self):
        for article in self.file_list:
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, article)):
                yield line.split()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply a corpus of `sentences` to the class-instantiation, as your code has done, you don't need to call `train()`. It will already have done that automatically, and your second `train()` is redundant. (I recommend doing all such operations with logging enabled at the INFO level, and review the lgos after each run to understand what is happening – things like two full start-to-finish trainings should stick out in the logs.)

The case where you would call `train()` explicitly is if you want more control over the interim steps. You leave the `sentences` out of the class-instantiation, but then it is required for you to perform two explicit steps: both one call to `build_vocab()` (for initial vocabulary scan) and then one call to `train()` (for actual multi-epoch training).

In that case, you can use gensim's native `.save()` to save the model *after* the vocabulary-discovery, to have a model that's ready for re-training and doesn't need to report that step.

So, you could re-load that vocabulary-built model multiple times, to different variables, to train in different ways. For some of the model's meta-parameters – like `window` or even `dm` mode – you can even tamper directly with their values on a model after vocabulary-building to try different variants.

However, if there are any changes to the corpus's words/word-frequencies, or to other parameters that affect the initialization that happens during `build_vocab()` (like vector `size`), then the initialization will be out of sync with the configuration you're trying, and you could get strange errors.

In such a case, the best course is to repeat the `build_vocab()` step entirely. (You could also look into the source code to see the individual steps performed by `build_vocab()`, and just patch/repeat the initialization steps that are needed, but that requires strong familiarity with the code.)

Comment: thank you,
i don't understand why vector size should affect the vocab building step.

Comment: Perhaps ideally, it wouldn't. But allocation of the internal vector arrays happens at the end of `build_vocab()`, because once the vocabulary size is fixed that allocation can proceed. (It used to be in a distinct last-step of `build_vocab()`, `finalize_vocab()`, but I'm not sure that clean distinction remains in current code.)